# Xcode Tab view + sqlite

Tags: sqlite3, xcode, sqlite

Под `mac os`.

Есть `tab view` с двумя вкладками. Есть база `sqlite` состоящая из таблицы в которой 2 столбца: имя и тип. В столбце тип 2 варианта: "Свой" и "Чужой". Вопрос, простите, может и не точный, но как мне выводить в tab view items вкладке все строки с типом "Свой" (чужой при переключении по вкладке)

`CoreData` и `NSPredicate` - да читал в справке эйпла. Но с выводом базы в `table view` из `sqlite3` разобрался, а вот как загнать в зависимости от типа в определенную вкладку `tab view`, не понимаю, заранее благодарен, всем кто сможет помочь.

Comment: @webbra, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментарию @AlexThumb. Судя по вопросу, Вам нужно изучить основную работу с CoreData и NSPredicate.

Comment: что такое столбец: UITableViewController, его секция? что такое tab view? UITabBarController? что используешь для работы с sqlite, FMDB?

Comment: Да секция. NSTabview рядом с box в oject libraty. Приложение создаю для mac os, да через FMDB, с помощью core даты до сих пор не понял как делается). NSTabviewController -  UITabBarController  вы про ios говорите? Скажите просто пример новичку как загнать данные в каждую вкладку tabvierwitems - обьекта tab view ?  :)